# I want to make the rows in this table collapsible/expandable

Tags: html, css, html-table

Find the code here, don't want to paste the entire thing... https://code.sololearn.com/W8odKz78WT07/#html

Or as an example, lets use this

```
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th><img class="isaaccrm" src="http://isaacintelligence.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/ISAAC-logo-cropped.png"/></th>
            <th><img class="zoho" src="http://i.imgur.com/R8vz9iG.png"/></th>
            <th><img class="salesforce" src="http://i.imgur.com/UhUHB4P.png"/></th>
            <th><img class="infusionsoft" src="http://i.imgur.com/iGzEnUr.png"/> </th>
            <th><img class="sugarcrm" src="http://i.imgur.com/weilyrP.png"/></th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th> <p class="comparisons">Operating Systems</p>
                <td class="center">Web</td>
                <td class="center">Web</td>
                <td class="center">Web</td>
                <td class="center">Web</td>
                <td class="center">Web</td>
            </th>

        </tr>
            <th><p class="comparisons">Mobile compatibility</p>
                <td><img style="padding-left:20px" title="iOS and Android" src="http://isaacintelligence.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/New-iOS-and-Android-1.png"></td>
                <td><img style="padding-left:30px" title="iOS, Android and Windows" src="http://isaacintelligence.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/New-iOS-and-Android-and-Windows-1.png"></td>
                <td><img style="padding-left:30px" title="iOS, Android and Windows" src="http://isaacintelligence.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/New-iOS-and-Android-and-Windows-1.png"></td>
                <td><img style="padding-left:20px" title="iOS and Android"  src="http://isaacintelligence.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/New-iOS-and-Android-1.png"></td>
                <td><img style="padding-left:60px" title="iOS, Android and Windows"  src="http://isaacintelligence.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/New-iOS-and-Android-and-Windows-1.png"></td>
            </th>
        </tr>
```

CSS being applied:

```
.isaaccrm {
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}

.zoho {
    height: 50px;
    width: 115px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;

}

.salesforce {
    height: 60px;
    width: 90px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.infusionsoft {
    height: 25px;
    width: 180px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.sugarcrm {
    height: 60px;
    width: 90px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 55px;
    float: right;
}

.comparisons {

    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    /* Make the comparison font into Lato*/

}
```

Is there any way I can make these rows collapsible, while showing the name of the Row (the `<p>` tag, so simply collapsing all of the `<td>`) still, while only using HTML/CSS? Or do I have to include JavaScript?

Comment: maybe this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926752/expand-collapse-table-rows-with-jquery

Comment: @BhavyaSinha - Ensure you do *all* the necessary edits, not just some.

Comment: Fix your markup, you are using invalid html structure

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this with `input:checked`, similar to this [Collapse and expand elements with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585064/collapse-and-expand-elements-with-css)

You have to place all the `input` tags before your table, then place `label` tags e.g. inside of each first cell in every row. you'll need `id/for` attributes on `input` and `label` tags.